# How to use Kotlin reflection to change the value of unchangeable property

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have this code:

```
fun main() {
    println("Program started")
    val obj = MyClass()
    obj.printXX()

    val objClass : Class<MyClass> = MyClass::class.java //Notice the use of "java" keyword
    val xxField = objClass.declaredFields[0]
    xxField.isAccessible = true //Crucial feature of java reflection
    xxField.set(obj, "xx is hacked and changed")

    obj.printXX()
    println("End of program")
}

class MyClass {
    private val xx = "This is xx"   //Inaccessible and Unchangeable  

    fun printXX() {
        println(xx)
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Program started
This is xx
xx is hacked and changed
End of program
```

Notice that the "xx" field is declared "private" (Inaccessible from outside) and it's a "val" (Unchangeable). Yet, by using **Java** reflection in **Kotlin** I was able to access and change the unchangeable field.

**How do I achieve the same result by only using Kotlin reflection without the help of Java?**

So far I've figured that I need an instance of "KMutableProperty1", but since the xx field is declared as a "val", I can only put my hands on a "KProperty1" instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin reflection doesn't provide this option afaik. The Kotlin/JVM reflect api has some helper methods for it, like [isAccessible](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/is-accessible.html), and then you can use java reflection for more advanced things.

As you can see in the API docs, the kotlin reflection api has quite different levels of support depending on the target platform: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/, just select a class that interests you, like KProperty, and toggle off JVM on top.

But in conclusion I do not think this is (currently) possible on other platforms than the JVM.